# PS Script: view all unique permissions for site and subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

I inherited a SharePoint Online old UI env and the client would to get a overview off all current security settings. I've found multiple tools (SysKit, Tru Sp auditor, ...) who will do almost what I need. But I doesn't give me a simple, transparant overview, level site/subsite.

I tried some scripting like ...

```
 #Import the required client dlls
 Import-Module   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
 Import-Module   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

 #Generic method to load the properties
 Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {
 param(
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject]$Object = $(throw "Please provide a Client Object"),
    [string]$PropertyName
 ) 
    $ctx = $Object.Context
    $load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 
    $type = $Object.GetType()
    $clientLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type) 


    $Parameter = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter(($type), $type.Name)
    $Expression = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda(
             [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Convert(
                 [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::PropertyOrField($Parameter,$PropertyName),
                 [System.Object]
             ),
             $($Parameter)
    )
    $ExpressionArray = [System.Array]::CreateInstance($Expression.GetType(), 1)
    $ExpressionArray.SetValue($Expression, 0)
    $clientLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($Object,$ExpressionArray))
 }


 #Mysite URL
 $site = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/'

 #Admin User Principal Name
 $admin = 'admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'

 #Get Password as secure String
 $password = Read-Host 'Supersecret Password' -AsSecureString

 #Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
 $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

 #Authenticate
 $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
 $context.Credentials = $credentials

 $list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('D1')
 $context.Load($list)


 Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $list -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"

 $context.ExecuteQuery()

 Write-Host $list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

All of them are getting an error on the commando

```
 $list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('D1')
```

Any ideas out here?

**edit: error**

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "List 'D1' does not exist at site with URL 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/'."
At line:7 char:2
+  $context.ExecuteQuery()
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

Comment: The error message could not be much clearer: your code expects a list with the title "D1" to exist on the site but fails to one.

Comment: I tried all kinds of listnames (D1, Documents, Documenten, Gedeelde documenten (native lang)) but all of them returned the same error. 'List does not exsist'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following scripts to check all the lists title:

```
$lists = $context.web.Lists
$context.load($lists)
$context.executeQuery()
foreach($list in $lists){
    Write-host $list.title}
```

Then try one of the titles to see if this issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

ShareGate comes with a number of good reports out of the box, and you can get a 14 days trial version. One of the best reports is that permissions overview